# How to draw a point in OpenGL ES3

Tags: c, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

How do I draw a point in OpenGL ES3?

I'm using the `GL_POINTS` Primitive.

Vertex Data

```c
// Position           Color
{{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}}
```

In the Vertex Shader

```c
gl_PointSize = 10.0;
```

This should render a Red Point on the Screen. But it's not getting rendered?

What is the problem?
How do I fix it?

Comment: IIRC (1,1, 0) puts your point in a corner of the screen. What happens when you place it at (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: i.e. `{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}`

Comment: I see a very small dot in the middle of the screen.

Comment: So, `gl_PointSize` is not working. How do I make it work?

Comment: Point size hasn't been very well supported historically. I think your best bet is to render two triangles covering the size you want.

Comment: `gl_PointSize` > 1.0 is not guaranteed to work at all. (it is hardware dependent)

Comment: Okay, is there any other way to change the size of the point?

Comment: No. There is not other way. You have to draw triangle primitives.